# Should a JS API Convert jqXHRs to Promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I've seen a pattern of people converting their jqXHR objects (ie. those things JQuery returns when you do an AJAX operation) in to promises.  For instance:

```
function doAJAX() {
    var jqXHR = $.get('http://www.example.com');
    return jqXHR.promise();
}
```

I've never bothered with this pattern because it doesn't seem to really offer anything.  When people talk about converting `$.Deffereds` to `$.Promises` they recommend doing so to prevent the user from prematurely resolving the deferred.  But jqXHRs already effectively *are* promises: they implement the promise interface and they can't be resolved prematurely.

But, I'm now working on a public-facing API, where I'm willing to bend over backwards (code-wise) if it will result in a better API for the customer.  So, my question is, am I missing anything?  Will throwing `.promise()` after every AJAX call that gets returned to the customer actually make things better for them in any way, or is this just an example of patternitis where people apply `.promise()` to their jqXHRs simply because they're used to doing it to their deferreds?

Comment: By doing so, you are limiting the user without providing any benefits. The user can no longer debug the xhr by looking at properties on the xhr because they don't have access to it (they could still use a breakpoint though). They also can't abort the request.

Comment: Only reason to do so is if you want the fact that your library is making an ajax call to be an implementation detail that you do not want to leak out into the public API.  For example, if your release the API and clients begin taking advantage of the fact that you are returning the jqXHR and they start calling non-promise methods upon it, then in v2 of your library you replace ajax with socket.io, then you will be facing a backward compatibility challenge with all the existing code that used your result as a jqXHR.  By calling `promise()` you prevent this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's jqXHR as returned from `$.get()` is already a fully functioning promise object, not a deferred object so it is already protected as a promise.  You don't need to convert it into one and doing so only hides existing jqXHR functionality.

So, you can already directly do this:

```
 $.get('http://www.example.com').done(function() {
     // your code here
 });
```

Straight from the [jQuery doc for `$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/);

> As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of
>   the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR,"
>   returned by $.get() implements the Promise interface, giving it all
>   the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred
>   object for more information). ...
>
> The Promise interface also allows jQuery's Ajax methods, including
>   $.get(), to chain multiple .done(), .fail(), and .always() callbacks
>   on a single request, and even to assign these callbacks after the
>   request may have completed. If the request is already complete, the
>   callback is fired immediately.

And, to your question:

> Will throwing .promise() after every AJAX call that gets returned to
>   the customer actually make things better for them in any way?

No, in my opinion, this will not help make it a better API as it will only serve to hide the jqXHR functionality and turn it into only a promise.  The jQXHR object is already a promise object and not a deferred object so the promise aspect of protection against people mucking with the deferred is already there.

---

The only reason I can think of to return ONLY a promise object from your API would be if you're truly trying to hide the fact that you're using jQuery underneath so you don't want there to be any way for the API user to use any other jQuery features.  But, unless you're also hiding ALL the argument functionality on the input to the Ajax call (so it can't look like jQuery on the input side of things either), then I see no point in hiding output functionality either.  After all, it is jQuery underneath so why go to all the trouble of abstracting/redefining the whole jQuery ajax interface.

Comment: The OP appears to be aware of all this. The question does not ask if converting to promises is required, but rather if it is desirable.

Comment: @Jon - That wasn't entirely clear from the OP's question, but I've added info to my answer about that.

Answer (score 2):

Most best practices are invented not to get things done now, but to get things done further down the road *as well*. It all
revolves around maintainability, reusability, flexibility etc. Requirements and technology change and your code should be robust enough to be able to adapt to those changes. The more tight coupling between components for instance, the harder it is to change a part without affecting other parts.

When designing a public facing API this is really important as well, probably even more so, since you should try not only making things easy for your future self, but also for all the users of your API. Backwards compatibility is one of these things users of an API really like, since it means they can upgrade your library w/o breaking any existing code. Obviously it's not always possible to make everything 100% backwards compatible (or sometimes it's not even desirable) It's a balancing act. Try to foresee possible future changes and code towards them. However this doesn't mean you should try jumping through hoops just because maybe one day this or that will change. You need to weigh the pros and cons and analyse the amount of work involved.

Now let's get to the question: 
If you return a jqXHR object from your method people will start using it not just as a promise, but as a full-fledged jqXHR object. They'll see it for what it is in the documentation, source code or their inspector and they _will_start using it as that. This means that their code expects not just a promise, but a jqXHR object, since that's what they are using. However this limits *you* the creator of the public API, because if one day down the road for whatever reason you don't want to return a jqXHR object you'll be making changes that aren't backwards compatible.

So let's assess how realistic this scenario is and what the solution is. 
Possible reasons why you might not be returning a jqXHR object in the future include (but are not limited to):

- What if you decide to use a different library instead of Jquery (for this method)?
- What if you need/want a different retrieval mechanism? For instance instead of retrieving data through ajax, you want to retrieve it from LocalStorage. Or maybe both?
- What if you want to wrap jquery promises with a promise library (for instance Q allows you to do this, since jquery promises aren't proper promises)?
- What if the flow changes and this method is only the first in a sequence of distributed processors?

In all of the above cases you will either jump through hoops (like for instance passing a stale jqXHR object around) to avoid breaking backward compatibility or you'll just break it. In all of the above cases people that have been using the returned object not only as a promise, but as a jqXHR object will have to change their code. This can be quite a substantial change.

Now let's get back to the balancing thing. **None of the above scenario's are a concern if the solution to avoid some of the potential headaches would be convoluted or elaborate, but it's not.** It's just *one simple thing*:

```
return jqXHR.promise();
```

The implementation detail is abstracted away, people don't know and especially *can't rely* on one specific implementation detail. I can almost guarantee you that it will save you trouble.

Many people seem to have a kneejerk reaction when it comes to best practices: "but it's totally possible to do it with [other solution]". Sure. Nobody's saying it's impossible or insurmountable. You just try to keep things easy both now and in the future.

Comment: Since jqXHR objects *are* promises, your points #3 and #6 are invalid. #1, #2, and #5 seem to say the same, #4 needs explanation (or is wrong)

Comment: @bergi yes they're promises, but jqXHR objects are a partial wrap of a native XMLHttpRequest object. If a user of the API relies on this, then any of the above changes _will_ break backwards compatibility.
And by no means is #1 and #2 the same. I'll think about #4.

Comment: I appreciate the post, but your points don't make a lot of sense.  1) If I ever switch away from jQuery, not using promises will be by far the least of my problems  2) if I change my retrieval mechanism, I'll have to change my code anyway; it doesn't matter whether I use promises or not, 3) this seems like an answer in search of a question ("you should use promises so you can use promises"), 4) I'm curious about this one: what memory leaks could not using promises cause?, 5) huh?  what does encapsulation have to do with any of this, 6) again, huh?  how does `$.ajax().promise` achieve that?

Comment: In short, I asked this question because I wanted to hear legitimate reasons, and you gave me a bunch of reasons.  However, their legitimacy is hard to understand (at best).  Could you possibly expound on and explain how calling promise on an xhr achieves any of the things you claimed?

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope it's more clear now. Maybe just one thing I didn't stress enough: it's not just about making things easy for yourself, but (primarily) for the users of your API as well.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your points better ... though don't really agree with them :)  But that was sort of the idea: to get the best answer possible for why I should be using `promise` (which I think you've done), so I can decide whether or not to use it based on good info.  Thanks.

Comment: Let me turn it around, why wouldn't you use `.promise()`?